# Making a group email list for multiple org members to get emails from external sources?

Tags: google-workspace, google-groups

In the past it was pretty straight forward to make a group with proper permissions without worry in [Google Apps' Groups](https://admin.google.com/ac/groups) Admin function. I frequently used it to create a recipient group for services like logging into a support system so multiple organization members could both login and receive emails simultaneously.  An example would be `support@domain.tld` would then route to `user.1@domain.tld`, `user.2@domain.tld` and `user.3@domain.tld`.

Unfortunately with their last update the water has become quite muddy in this regard. The intuitiveness level has dropped through the floor. Could someone please advise as to whether or not the following are the correct settings for the desired external submission only effect that's desired?

Screenshot:
[image: group "permissions" panel that's junk after the update]